# create a folder in local computer from online system in php

Tags: php

I want to save a file from the online system and save it into specific,ex. C:/myFolder/. So,if in the C:/ there is no myFolder name,the system will automatically detect and create the folder in C drive, and save the file into that folder. When I try system locally, it can create the folder and the file into C drive.

But when it upload my file into the server, the folder was created within the server, not in the local computer. Can anyone help me how to solve this? how to create a folder in local computer and save file into that folder from online system?

Below is the code that works when the system runs locally:

```
$directory = 'C:/sales/'.$filename.'.txt';

$path_name = 'C:/sales/';

if ( ! is_dir($path_name)) {
    mkdir($path_name);
}

if(mysql_num_rows($query))
{
    $fp = fopen($directory, 'w');

    if($fp)
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($query); $i++)
        {
            $f = mysql_fetch_array($query);

            $orderFee_q = mysql_query("select * from sales_order where status in ('waiting', 'waiting1', 'waiting2', 'approved') and outstanding = 'N' order by so_no desc");
            $get_orderFee = mysql_fetch_array($orderFee_q);

            $line = $f["id"]."\t".$f["so_no"];

            if(trim($line) != '') {fputs($fp, $line."\r\n");}
        }
    }

    fclose($fp);
}


$download_name = basename($filename);

if(file_exists($filename))
{
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$download_name);
header('X-SendFile: '.$filename);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header("Expires: 0");
readfile($filename);
}
```

Comment: This would require actions from the client (manual or automated). You can't do it by running some code in your server.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, you can't do that in php or any other server side language.

Edit:
Reason is simple server side application and scripts have access only to local resources where they are launched. So when you run your application on local computer, everything works as you wish for. But because of how HTTP works and because of safety reasons you cannot access user local files.

Comment: This answer is obviously the only correct answer, but do you care to elaborate a bit for educational purposes?

Comment: Only way to accomplish this is to make it user-side-application, so probably JAVA (don't know how it handles user files while embeding on webpage), Active-X, or you have to create executable in c++/C#/etc which will download the file, and save it where you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a desktop application that interacts with your server, which would allow you to do something like this.

Comment: may i know what kind of application is that? how it can be done to interact with server?

Comment: In the .NET framework, for example, you can make WinForms applications that use WinSock to connect to a server. I am not whether this can be used to connect to an Apache server, but there must be equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

You can not tell the user where to save the file you sending. Even with JavaScript. Server Site languages can manipulata the files on the server, not on the client's machine, by defaylt.But anyway it is not possible to access client's files without the permision of the client. Possibly this could be done by an ActiveX component, but client should agree and accept this action. Otherwise untill now your computer would have more virusese than your files. So the browser makes a protected invironment for safe browsing. You have already set the name of the file you are sending ... so that's the max possible you can do server side.